# Extracting frequency derivative from STFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, wavelets

I have a signal that oscillates on short timescales and changes frequency of that oscillation on larger scales. If I do a Short Time Fourier Transform(STFT) or a constant Q transform, I get a feature in frequency space that moves in time. See for example the 2nd row plot of the measurement of gravitational waves.

[image: Ligo detection of gravitational waves - sept 2017]

I am interested in the time derivative of f, an estimate of $\dot{f}$. If I have a distribution of f at each timestep, is there a method or algorithm to get a distribution of $\dot{f} (f)$ at each timestep?

Thanks and Best,

Niklas

Comment: I very much appreciate the subject, but this question belongs [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/84816/why-does-varying-n-fft-change-the-range-of-x-axis-values-when-plotting-stft)